# Combining Datatable and update in c#

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a `DataTable` inside a function,

```
public static DataTable FormulaandRowOrder(DataTable dtRoworder)
{
    DataTable table1 = new DataTable();
    // code here

    return table1;  
}
```

`tables1` has columns like `Col1` and `Col2`.

After calling a function for ex my function name is `DataFeed`.

```
public static DataTable[] DataFeed (DataTable table2, DataTable table3)
{
    //code here

    return new DataTable[] { table2, table3 };
}
```

the above function does some coding and has some values in `table3`. and the `table3` has the same column as `Col1` and `Col2`

Now I would like to update the `table1` with `table3` values. How can I do that?
`table1` and `table3` has the same structure, but `table3` contains some new values, which have to be added to the `table1`.

Comment: does all the tables has same structure i.e. columns ?

Comment: ya table1 and table3 has same structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if table3 contain all the rows that are in table1 and also contain some new rows then simply use
`table1.clear();`
`table1.Merge(table3)`

otherwise get all the new rows from table3 using Linq and add it in to table1 
C# code is......

```
var rowNotIntable1 = table3.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("col1"))
                                              .Except(table1.AsEnumerable().Select(r =>r.Field<string>("col1")));

                                if (rowNotIntable1 .Count() > 0)
                                {
                                    DataTable dt = (from row in table3.AsEnumerable()
                                                    join id in rowNotIntable1 
                                                        on row.Field<string>("col1") equals id
                                                    select row).CopyToDataTable();
            }
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                                    {
            table1.ImportRow(row);
            table1.AcceptChanges();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to read all the new rows from table3 and copy them into table1. You can accomplish this via LINQ or a simple for cycle.